# Software to create an automated bot for desktop applications

Tags: automation, image-recognition, artificial-intelligence

Please recommend software that can help to write an automated bot that can interact with other desktop applications.

I'm looking for something that can help me write a bot for desktop games.

- scan whole desktop
- recognize text and custom graphics and ability to build logic on top of that
- performa basic UI interaction actions: mouse, keyboard actions

P.S. I was thinking about some automation software like autoit, selenium, etc, but haven't used those and not sure they can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for was developed as [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) by the Sikuli Lab at the University of Colorado Boulder and is now maintained and further developed as [SikuliX](https://github.com/RaiMan) by RaiMan and the open source community.

It is free, gratis & open source (MIT Licenced) and provides:

- Search the Desktop visually for specific components & events
- Interact with those components, *click, type, ect.*
- IDE for putting things together & basic scripting
- Scriptable in Python, Ruby or JavaScript.

Current Documents for the 2014 version are [here](http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) there is a new version SikuliX2 under development at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks, looks nice, I'll give it a try.